# Is there a way to use homestead/laravel with desktop?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I would like to cancel this shared folder feature and use homestead vagrant with desktop environment.

Because otherwise it's creates problems with windows folder name limitations when using npm install command.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: You have `ssh` access and thereby the possibility to `scp` into it. You could also create a local git environment. Which problems are you experiencing specifically?

Comment: @Dencker this : https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3697 and that: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/windows-10-vagrant-virtualbox-homestead

Comment: Did you try any of the solutions provided there?

Comment: I have tried them. Started to working until restarting windows. And after every restart it's needs all those steps again and again.

Comment: I think it's because the box gets provisioned on every restart. You might need to put the steps into Homesteads [Vagrantfile](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/).

Comment: i was using homestead for 1 year on my macbook without any problems. the problem is sometimes local.dev homestead site is reachable sometimes it doesn't. i think you didn't get it. even virtualbox released a fix for that but it also doesn't work after making few bunch of windows updates https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13665

Comment: Your Mac runs on a unix-kernel, whereas Windows runs on NT, which is substantially different. But you said that the steps made it work, so instead of doing them manually, you might be able to automate them when you run `homestead up`.

Comment: i am pretty sure that there is no way to automate NT file system for increasing char limit. @Dencker